# File descriptor leak in third party Java library

Tags: java, file

I am using a third party library that uses `RandomAccesFile`. In one of the constructors, it opens the file (retrieves the descriptor) and tried to read header afterwards. If there is an exception while reading the header, the `RandomAccesFile` that was opened in the previous step is not closed and the file descriptor will be held until the GC does its job.

I cannot rely on GC to clear file descriptors by collecting the unreferenced `RandomAccesFile` instances, because this problem is not related to the memory usage.

Even if I wanted to close the `RandomAccesFile` myself, I cannot access it since the object that opened the `RandomAccesFile` is never created due to an exception in its constructor.

Here are the two constructors from the library:

I am creating `FileObjectQueue` instance

```
public FileObjectQueue(File file, FileObjectQueue.Converter<T> converter) throws IOException {
    this.file = file;
    this.converter = converter;
    this.queueFile = new QueueFile(file);
}
```

And it creates `QueueFile`, which is causing the leak.

```
final RandomAccessFile raf;

public QueueFile(File file) throws IOException {
    if (!file.exists()) {
        initialize(file);
    }

    this.raf = open(file);
    this.readHeader();
}
```

As you can see extending these classes won't help since these are the only constructors in these classes.

I do not want to use reflection or bytecode manipulation.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is it that you want exactly? If you want to fix the library, fork it and fix it.

Comment: Can you confirm that `raf` is private in `QueueFile` and does not have a setter? Otherwise you indeed could likely subclass it.

Comment: @eis This is an old version of the library and barely supported. It would take a long time for my PR tom be accepted. Then I would need a new release and bump the version of the library across my product versions that were released in the meantime. Using the fork is not acceptable due to licencing and maintenance.

Comment: @Harald Unfortunately `raf` is package protected and final.